# Set id on a csv import for a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, has-and-belongs-to-many, csv-import

I have two models in my app: `list.rb` and `contacts.rb`, they have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.
I have the following method in my `contacts_controller.rb`:

```
def import
  Contact.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to contacts_path, notice: "Contacts were imported."
end
```

I am calling his method after creating a `List` in the `list#create` action. how can I `set/input` the `list_id` into this import method above, where the records are created through a `csv` file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need first get the list, like you do for example in the `show` method. Make sure that `import` is a member-route.

```
@list = List.find(params[:id])
```

You need then modify your `import` method, that it takes a second parameter for your list.

```
def Contact.import_for_list(file, list)
   # loop over csv lines
     # for each line you create a contact element
     # and then add the new contact element to the list
     list.contacts << newly_created_contact

     # or you create the contact from the list object
     list.contacts.build(....)
   # depending how you created the objects you need to save them explicitly
end
```

And lastly you call your modified method

```
def import
  @list = List.find(params[:id])
  Contact.import_for_list(params[:file], @list)
  redirect_to contacts_path, notice: "Contacts were imported."
end
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. import is a collection of contacts, I have not gotten the csv import working otherwise. I know how to set the list according to your suggestion '@list = List.find(params[:id])' but how to I pass the list_id in since I am going over from the list model to the contacts model? I think I am getting there, I now simply just get the error that the list_id is empty. Thanks again for you help, as you can see I am very new to rails.